# Why does blogdown::serve_site() take so long on my website?

Tags: r, blogdown

I have built a website using blogdown ([www.simoncoulombe.com](http://www.simoncoulombe.com), serving https://github.com/simoncoulombe/snippets).   When I add a new post (say just a text post), it will knit fast, but then spends 5-8 minutes "building web site".

My website is very heavy and has a few leaflet maps that are like 40MB.  Is that the problem?  Maybe I could just move them off to an S3 bucket?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "spends 5-8 minutes 'building web site'"? Who built the website? And how? I ran `blogdown::build_site()` on your website and it took 2.5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Yihui. Rstudio takes 5-8 minutes to return to the prompt after I type blogdown::serve_site() .   I'm going to try on a different computer and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Yihui,  I finally tried on a new computer and it built in a couple seconds.  Guess my R install was broken.

Comment: Okay, good to know that it worked fine on your new computer!

Comment: Huge thanks for jumping in.  Sorry for bothering you - That's the basics, I should have checked that before asking. (and diverting you from your amazing works :)